# Laravel spatie permission wrong model_type in query

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

Hello everyone) I have a problem with Spatie laravel permission.
I installed this module according to the documentation. Create role Admin, and added new record in table model_has_roles:

role_id: 1 (1 is id of admin role)

model_type: App\Models\User (like in our another project where this are working)

model_id: id of my user

But this is not working. I began see, why this is not working. I saw query logs. There was wrong "where". It was where model_id = 123 and model_type = 1

why model_type is 1 in this query? It's working in another project there model_type is App\Models\User in DB

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I think in our another project old version this module.
I added code below in my User model (according documentation) and this worked

```
public function getMorphClass(): string
{
    return __CLASS__;
}
```